# Theorem that proof that Analytic function is constant in some region

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F(z,\theta)$ be a complex function in $\theta$ and $z.$ Suppose that for  $\theta \in D \equiv \{x \in \mathbb{C}: \mid x \mid <1\}$, $F(z,\theta)$ is analytic in $D$. Now suppose for $\phi \in \mathbb{R} $ we have $F(z,\phi)=F(z,0).$ What theorem says that $F(z,\theta)$ is constant in $D$?

Comment: Is $f$ analytic in each variable?

Comment: yes in that  region

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the statement clearly but I hope this answers your question: $F(z,\phi)-F(z,0)$ is analytic in $\phi$ and it vanishes on the real line. Since the zeros of this function have a limit point it is identically $0$ so $F(z,\phi)$ is a constant for each $z$.

Comment: could you give me  a reference for your answer

Comment: @amiltonmoreira See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Comment: what you mean is this , since $F(z,\phi)=F(z,0)$ for all $\phi \in R$ so by the identity theorem $F(z, \theta)=F(z,0) $for each $z$?